# When using github do include everything then ignore node_modules or install your apl then pull?

Tags: git, github

Ive started using github. Ive read that you should not include node_modules. So how would this work if I need to pull? For example with svelte. Should I include everything in the initial commit including the svelte and node_modules directories then clone and ignore them on subsequent pulls? Or install a fresh version then just pull the added files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you've tracked a file, `.gitignore` no longer applies to those tracked files as long as they're tracked.  So if you add your `node_modules` in the first commit and then add it to `.gitignore`, it won't be ignored, and it will be tracked in this history.

In general, you should set up your `.gitignore` to exclude `node_modules` and anything else you don't want to include before your initial commit, and you should be careful to add additional things to `.gitignore` as necessary so as to not commit files at all that you don't want in the repository.

Note that [Git doesn't provide a way to ignore tracked files at all](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files).  If they are tracked, changes will be reflected in the working tree.